# Java Optional if else logic

Tags: java

I have a method that searches a customer in the DB, if found, it returns that customer, otherwise, it creates a new one.

```
private Customer getProjectCustomer(String customerCode) {
    Optional<Customer> customerInDB = customerRepository.findByCode(customerCode);

    if (!customerInDB.isPresent()) {
        //call to remote service to get the customer from the remote service
        Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
        ..some sets
        return customerRepository.save(newCustomer);
    }

    return customerInDB.get();
}
```

I have the feeling that this is not the correct way to use the Java Optional, however, I don't really know if there is a better more functional approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`Optional.orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier))

```
private Customer getProjectCustomer(String customerCode) {
    return customerRepository.findByCode(customerCode)
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
                // ...
                return customerRepository.save(newCustomer);
            });
}
```